# Unable to control slider captcha jquery using Selenium Webdrive?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to record **slider captcha** given on our client site.

We have get this concept from other site named as http://www.fmylife.com/signup

This have slider captcha for registration

I have try to use selenium webdriver action builder

```
public class TestFmylife {
    WebDriver driver;
    Selenium selenium;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startSelenium() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.fmylife.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void stopSelenium() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFmylife() {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.click("link=Sign up");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("name=login", "testfmylife");
        selenium.type("name=pass", "123@fmylife");
        selenium.type("name=passc", "123@fmylife");
        selenium.type("name=mail", "testfmylife@gmail.com");

        Point MyPoint= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bgSlider']")).getLocation();

        WebElement someElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bgSlider']"));

        System.out.println(MyPoint.x+"--------"+MyPoint.y);


        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

        Action dragAndDrop =  builder.clickAndHold(someElement).moveByOffset(MyPoint.x,(MyPoint.y + 100)).release().build();

        dragAndDrop.perform();

        selenium.click("css=div.form > div.ok > input[type=\"submit\"]");
    }
}
```

But I can't move slider using this code

Help me to sort this out

Answer (score 0):

I used the dragAndDropBy method of the Actions class (java.lang.Object
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions) and moved the slider by 200 points horizontally . Please give the following code a try:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.fmylife.com/signup");
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Slider']"));
Actions builder = new Actions (driver);
builder.dragAndDropBy(slider, 200, 0).build().perform();
```

Comment: Is this working in your system?? Its not working in my system

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
   .moveToElement(otherElement)
   .release(otherElement)
   .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

more can be found at - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions

You can use locator as follows -

```
String xto=Integer.toString(LocatorTo.getLocation().x);
String yto=Integer.toString(LocatorTo.getLocation().y);
```

Working code-

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/");
//Identify WebElement
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='slider']/a"));

//Using Action Class
Actions move = new Actions(driver);
Action action = move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();
action.perform();

driver.quit();
```

Source - https://gist.github.com/2497551

Comment: I have tried all above solutions but none of those working. please can you try it on your pc and send me whole stuff?

Answer (score 0):

If your slider is  like mine

[image]

with a "slider handle" (an <a/> tag as the box with the value "5ft 5") within a "slider track" (a <div> tag as the long black bar) then the following code will in C# will work to move the slider handle a percentage along the slider track.

```
public void SetSliderPercentage(string sliderHandleXpath, string sliderTrackXpath, int percentage)
{
    var sliderHandle = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(sliderHandleXpath));
    var sliderTrack = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(sliderTrackXpath));
    var width = int.Parse(sliderTrack.GetCssValue("width").Replace("px", ""));
    var dx = (int)(percentage / 100.0 * width);
    new Actions(driver)
                .DragAndDropToOffset(sliderHandle, dx, 0)
                .Build()
                .Perform();
}
```