# Slider movement possible in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move Horizontal Slider or Vertical Slider of jQuery using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138449/how-to-move-horizontal-slider-or-vertical-slider-of-jquery-using-selenium-webdri)

There are many examples of slider in internet like

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Is it possible to move the slider using Selenium?

Comment: refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966287/unable-to-control-slider-captcha-jquery-using-selenium-webdrive/12050145

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Working code-

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/");
//Identify WebElement
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='slider']/a"));

//Using Action Class
Actions move = new Actions(driver);
Action action = move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();
action.perform();

driver.quit();
```

Source - https://gist.github.com/2497551

Comment: This is actually incorrect.  The ".build()" method is not required here.

Comment: above code is not work for me.

Comment: How about the VB code?

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried the [`Action`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) interface?

Especially the point "Generating Action chains" should help you

```
/**
 * Moves a jQuery slider to percental position, don't care about directions
 * @param slider to move
 * @param percent to set the slider
 */
public void moveSliderToPercent(WebElement slider, int percent){

    Actions builder = new Actions(this.driver);

    Action dragAndDrop;

    int height = slider.getSize().getHeight();
    int width = slider.getSize().getWidth();


    if(width>height){
        //highly likely a horizontal slider
        dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(slider).moveByOffset(-(width/2),0).
                       moveByOffset((int)((width/100)*percent),0).
                       release().build();
    }else{
        //highly likely a vertical slider
        dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(slider).moveByOffset(0, -(height/2)).
                       moveByOffset(0,(int)((height/100)*percent)).
                       release().build();
    }


    dragAndDrop.perform();

}
```

Comment: The above code is not working fine for me. And i tried with the posted site `http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/` too. It's not working.

Comment: I have no recurring tests for that... but it definitely worked when I posted it ;)