# Selenium IDE does not change PrimeFaces control

Tags: java, selenium, primefaces, selenium-ide

we have a web form developed by Java and PrimeFaces framework. In this form we have a ui control which is called slider. It contanins a button on a horizontal line. When we move the button it gives us a number in [50,99] range.

The problem is when i use Selenium IDE to record test cases, Selenium is not able to move the slider control. How can i achieve this?

Here is what my slider looks like:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122824/slider-movement-possible-in-selenium http://onlineseleniumtraining.com/how-to-work-with-jquery-ui-slider-using-selenium-webdriver-action-builder/ http://onlineseleniumtraining.com/how-to-work-with-jquery-ui-slider-using-selenium-webdriver-action-builder-2/