# selenium webdriver slider error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is not working. I want the slider to move. All the buttons of the slider have the same xpath. I have need to move only the departure slider option, how to do it. I have tried the below code in two ways but nothing works.

public class task {

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "g://geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.cheapoair.com/");
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember746']")).sendKeys("DFW");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember751']")).sendKeys("JFK");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='owFlight']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='departCalendar_0']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calendarCompId']/section/div/div[1]/ol/div[26]/li")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember751']")).sendKeys("JFK");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='owFlight']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember730']/section/form/input")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Actions a = new Actions(driver);

    //WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));
    //WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]"));
    //a.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();
```

WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='slider-handle round']"));
a.clickAndHold(slider).moveByOffset(30, 0).release(slider).build().perform();

```
}
```

}

Comment: Check out this solution...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122824/slider-movement-possible-in-selenium

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slider movement possible in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122824/slider-movement-possible-in-selenium)