# Trying to auto complete web form slider with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm a beginner to Python, this is my first attempt at a complete program of my own idea. Trying to make a program to auto fill a website using Selenium so far, now I've got to a point in the form that requires annual income to be selected from a sliding scale element. How can I use Selenium or another module to slide the element to a predefined position (£ value)?

Preferably a random value between say £20,000 and £30,000 for example

[image]

I have tried googling but no luck. Also other similar questions on stack overflow - the answers have comments saying they do not work. I have tried a few and cannot get them working myself.

Below is the code I am currently using

```
percent = 50

browser.switch_to_frame(0)
browser.switch_to_active_element()

slidebar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="annualRangeWrap"]/a')
height = slidebar.size['50']
width = slidebar.size['342']

move = ActionChains(driver); 

slider = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="annualRangeWrap"]/a')

if width > height:

    move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(percent * width / 100, 0).release().perform()
else:

    move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(percent * height / 100, 0).release().perform()

browser.switch_to_default_content()
```

This is the code from inspect element

```
<div class="question" id="annualRangeWrap" style="display: block;"><div class="rangeLabel">Annual income</div>

<div class="rangeWrap"><div class="rangeLow">£0</div><div class="rangeNum"><span>Slide to select</span></div>
<div class="rangeHigh">£50,001+</div>
<div class="affRangeSlider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-min" style="width: 0%;"></div>
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a></div></div></div>
''<div class="rangeLabel">Annual income</div><div class="rangeWrap"><div class="rangeLow">£0</div><div class="rangeNum">
<span>Slide to select</span></div><div class="rangeHigh">£50,001+</div>
<div class="affRangeSlider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-min" style="width: 0%;"></div>
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a></div></div>'
```

I've tried using ID, class, Xpath. I cannot figure out where i am going wrong

This is typically what i get at traceback. I've tried using different elements in combo but its always "cannot find 'xxxxx' "

```
File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\New folder (2)\VeryAutoForm.py", line 138, in <module>
    slidebar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="annualRangeWrap"]/a')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="annualRangeWrap"]/a"}
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122824/slider-movement-possible-in-selenium

Comment: Your code trials and error trace logs (if any)?

Comment: I have tried the other questions ... answers don't seem to work for myself and others who have commented.

Comment: slidebar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="annualRangeWrap"]/a')

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution. May of been obvious to anyone who knows css but i'm still a novice. The code that worked for me was so simple. Of course change the css selector to match your own. I added the percent for my solution yours likely will be different

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
percent = random.randint(150, 340)

slider = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#totalRangeWrap > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(2)")

move = ActionChains(browser)
move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(percent, 0).release().perform()
```